# React hook error is returning an empty object

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I want to display the error message on the paragraph element, but the error (message) returns an empty object. Here's the code

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";

export default function FormInputs() {
  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm();
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
        <div className="mb-5 mt-5">
          <label
            htmlFor="exampleFormControlTextarea1"
            className="form-label mb-3"
          >
            Name
          </label>
          <input
            type="text"
            name="name"
            className="form-control form-control-lg"
            id="exampleFormControlTextarea1"
            placeholder="Mide Olabanji"
          />
        </div>
        <div className="mb-5">
          <label htmlFor="exampleFormControlInput1" className="form-label mb-3">
            Email address <span className="required"> *</span>
          </label>
          <input
            type="email"
            name="email"
            className="form-control form-control-lg"
            id="exampleFormControlInput1"
            placeholder="Mideolabanji@devmail.com"
            {...register("email", { required: "Please include your email" })}
          />
        </div>
        <h6>{error.email.message}</h6>
<footer>
          <a href="/next">
            <input
              type="submit"
              className="btn btn-lg mt-5 ms-2 next-btn"
              value="Next"
            />
          </a>
          </footer>
```

The object is only updated on submit so i tried to use state to update it:

```
const [error, setError] = useState("");

function onSubmit(data) {
    console.log(data);
    setError(errors.email.message);
  }
...
<h6>{error}</h6>
```

but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Have you found any solution for this issues ?

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure you're accessing the `errors` object and not `error` *(you might be doing it correctly but your code is broken up into 2 snippets so its a bit confusing)*
2. Remove the `name="email"` from your input as `{...register()}` returns a name. I assume this is where you error is at.

properties `type`, `classname`, `placeholder` are all okay to have but the register function returns `onChange`, `onBlur`, `ref` and `name` so there is no need to override it as I assume it will cause errors

```html
          <input
            type="email"
            className="form-control form-control-lg"
            id="exampleFormControlInput1"
            placeholder="Mideolabanji@devmail.com"
            {...register("email", { required: "Please include your email" })}
          />
```